# Problema al insertar nodos en arbol n-ario a partir de un archivo txt

Tags: java

tengo un problema al insertar nodos en mi clase clase árbol mediante la lectura de archivos txt, mi problema es que cuando almaceno todas las líneas de mi código en una lista y a la hora que quiero acceder a la lista para crear los objetos, sea con un for o quemandolos manualmente, solo me deja hacer una sola inserción, ya sea insertar raíz o insertar un nodo normal y no me genera ningun error, cuando ejecuto el recorrer arbol solo me muestra que se almaceno la primera linea que ingrese, el resto no aparece, ayuda por favor, es para entregar en un par de dias y levo semanas intentando solucionarlo, anexo mi codigo si me pueden ayudar.

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
import Logica.*;

public class presentacion  {

    
    public static <T> void main(String[] args)  
    {
        Archivo objArchivo= new Archivo();
        ArrayList<String[]> lineas= new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArbolNArio<T> miArbol=new ArbolNArio<T>();
        String[] Auxiliar;      
        lineas=objArchivo.leerArchivo();
        String aux1,aux2;
        
        //miArbol.insertarRaiz(lineas.get(1)[0]);
        
        
        for (int i = 2; i < lineas.size(); i++) 
        {
            aux1=lineas.get(i)[0];
            aux2=lineas.get(i)[1];
            System.out.println(aux1 + " - " + aux2 );
            miArbol.instertar(aux1, aux2);
            
        }
        
        

        /*Auxiliar=lineas.get(2);
        miArbol.insertarRaiz(Auxiliar[0]);
        miArbol.instertar(Auxiliar[0], Auxiliar[1]);
        miArbol.instertar(Auxiliar[0], Auxiliar[1]);
        Auxiliar=lineas.get(3);
        miArbol.instertar(Auxiliar[0], Auxiliar[1]);*/
        
        
        
        
        /*miArbol.instertar("A", "E");
        miArbol.instertar("A", "L");
        miArbol.instertar("A", "T");
        
        
        miArbol.instertar("E", "B");*/
        miArbol.recorrer();
        

    }
    
    
}'
'package Logica;



public class ArbolNArio<T> 
{
    private Nodo<T> raiz;
    public ArbolNArio() {
        this.raiz = null;
        }

    public Nodo<T> getRaiz() {
        return raiz;
    }

    public void setRaiz(Nodo<T> raiz) {
        this.raiz = raiz;
    } 
    public void insertarRaiz(Comparable elemento) 
    {
        
        insertar(raiz,null,elemento);
    }
    public void instertar(Comparable posicion,Comparable elemento) 
    {
        insertar(raiz, posicion, elemento);
    }
    private void insertar(Nodo<T> arbol,Comparable posicion,Comparable elemento) 
    {
        Nodo<T> nuevoNodo=new Nodo(elemento);
            if(raiz==null) 
            {
                raiz=nuevoNodo;//VERIFICA SI EL ARBOL ESTÁ VACIO, SI LO ESTÁ SE CREA UN ARBOL CON RAIZ ELEMENTO 
                
            }
            else 
            {
                if(posicion==arbol.getElemento()) 
                {
                    arbol.agregarHijo(nuevoNodo);//VERIFICA SI LA POSICION INGRESADA ES IGUAL AL NODO ACTUAL
                }
                else
                {
                    //SI NO ES ASI, ENTRARÁ A CADA UNO DE LOS HIJOS DEL NODO ACTUAL A COMPARAR
                    for (int i = 0; i < arbol.getHijos().size(); i++) 
                    {
                        if(posicion==arbol.getHijos().get(i).getElemento()) 
                        {
                            arbol.getHijos().get(i).agregarHijo(nuevoNodo);//AQUI PREGUNTO SI LA POSICION ES IGUAL A UNO DE LOS HIJOS DE LA RAIZ Y SI ES ASI INGRESE UN NUEVO HIJO A ESE HIJO
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            
                            insertar(arbol.getHijos().get(i),posicion, elemento);//SINO ES ASI VOLVERA A INGRESAR EN CADA UNO DE LOS NODOS HIJOS DE ESE NODO
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
    public void recorrer() 
    {
        recorrer(raiz);
    }
    
    public void recorrer(Nodo<T> NODO) 
    {
        System.out.println(NODO.getElemento());
        for (int i = 0; i < NODO.getHijos().size(); i++) 
        {
            recorrer( NODO.getHijos().get(i));
        }
    }
    
    

}
'
'package Logica;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Nodo <T> 
{
    private T elemento;
    private ArrayList <Nodo<T>> hijos;
    
    public Nodo (T elemento) 
    {
        this.elemento=elemento;
        this.hijos= new ArrayList<Nodo<T>>();
    }
    public Nodo(Nodo<T> nodo) 
    {
        this.elemento=nodo.getElemento();
        this.hijos=new ArrayList<Nodo<T>>();
    }   

    public T getElemento() {
        return elemento;
    }

    public void setElemento(T elemento) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }

    public ArrayList<Nodo<T>> getHijos() {
        return hijos;
    }
    public void setHijos(ArrayList<Nodo<T>> hijos) {
        this.hijos = hijos;
    }

    public void agregarHijo(Nodo<T> hijo) 
    {       
        hijos.add(hijo);   
    } 
    

}
'
'package Logica;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Archivo {
    private File archivo;
    private BufferedReader archivoEntrada;
    public Archivo() {
        archivo=new File("src\\\\DocumentoPrueba.txt");
        if(archivo.exists()==false) {
            try {
                archivo.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    public void Archivo2(){
        
        try {
            archivoEntrada= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\DocumentoPrueba.txt"));
             
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> leerArchivo(){
        
        String lineaArchivo="";
        String[] lineaPartida=null;
        ArrayList<String[]> lineas= new ArrayList<String[]>();
        
        try {
            archivoEntrada= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
            while(lineaArchivo!=null){
                
                lineaArchivo=archivoEntrada.readLine();
                
                if(lineaArchivo!=null) {
                    
                    lineaPartida=lineaArchivo.split("-");
                    lineas.add(lineaPartida);
                    
                }
                    
            }
            archivoEntrada.close();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("¡Ha ocurrido un error!");
            e.getMessage();
        }
        
        return lineas;
    }
    
    

}
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contenido del archivo txt:

```
A-B-C-D
B-F-G
G-Z-Y
```

Función `main()` modificada:

```
public static <T> void main(String[] args) {

    Archivo objArchivo = new Archivo();
    ArrayList<String[]> lineas;
    ArbolNArio<T> miArbol = new ArbolNArio<T>();
    lineas = objArchivo.leerArchivo();


    String raiz = "";

    miArbol.insertarRaiz(raiz);

    for (String[] linea : lineas) {
        // en la raiz se inserta el primer elemento de la línea
        miArbol.instertar(raiz, linea[0]);
        // el primer elemento de la lína se convierte en la raíz del resto de la línea
        String raizLocal = linea[0];
        // el resto de elementos en la lista se insertan en la raizLocal
        for (int j = 1; j < linea.length; j++) {
            miArbol.instertar(raizLocal, linea[j]);
        }
    }


    miArbol.recorrer();


}
```

Salida del método `recorrer()`:

```
----A
--------B
--------C
--------D
----B
--------F
--------G
----G
--------Z
--------Y
```

**Actualización**

Adaptación de la función `main()` para cumplir las condiciones de los datos en el archivo:

```
public static <T> void main(String[] args) {

        Archivo objArchivo = new Archivo();
        ArrayList<String[]> lineas;
        ArbolNArio<T> miArbol = new ArbolNArio<T>();
        lineas = objArchivo.leerArchivo();

        String raiz;

        // 1. la primera línea es para decidir si será de enteros o cadenas
        String decicion = lineas.get(0)[0];// ? que se debe hacer?

        // 2. la segunda línea será la raíz
        raiz = lineas.get(1)[0];
        miArbol.insertarRaiz(raiz);

        // 3. insertar el segundo elemento
        // el primer elemento será la raíz

        for (int i = 2; i < lineas.size(); i++) {
            String[] linea = lineas.get(i);
            // línea en 0 es la raíz, linea en 1 el elemento
            miArbol.insertar(linea[0],linea[1]);
        }

        miArbol.recorrer();


    }
```

**NOTA**

En el método `insertar()` de la clase `ArbolNArio` se comparan objetos usando el operador `==` eso es un error. Los objetos deben compararse usando el método `equals()`.

La línea:

```
if(posicion == arbol.getElemento())
```

Debe ser:

```
if(posicion.equals(arbol.getElemento()))
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, como te puntuó? soy nuevo, de verdad gracias

Comment: Disculpa tanta molestia amigo pero ahora mi profesor me mando el archivo txt que debe leer, con las siguientes reglas,la primera linea es para definir si el arbol es de caracteres o de enteros debe insertar solo a partir de la segunda linea, la cual deberá ser la raiz, a partir de la tercera linea solo debe insertar los segundos acaracteres de cada linea 0
A
A-E
A-L
A-T
E-B
E-F
E-H
T-W
F-M
F-N
W-Y
W-Z me podrías orientar, por favor?

Comment: está bien, intentares resolverlo, si ya no puedo y e tiempo se me hecha encima buscaré tu ayuda de nuevo. muchas gracias.

Comment: Agregué la actualización para cumplir con las condiciones del archivo. Mientras lo implementaba encontré un error en el código que impedía que el código funcionara. Lo agregué como una nota para que lo revises.

Comment: muchísimas gracias, de verdad estuve dándole hasta tarde con eso y logre medio avanzar en algunas cosas pero nunca podía llenar de forma correcta